# Problem with parsing variables in a R function

Tags: r, statistics, tidyverse, data-handling

I'm working with a dataset in R and I want to create a function that separates values into three categories based on quartiles. Values below the first quartile (Q1) should be labeled "Low expression", values above the third quartile (Q3) should be labeled "High expression", and everything else should be labeled "NA".

I wrote the following function, but it keeps considering everything as high expression. Can someone help me with this one?

#### function

```r
library(tidyverse)


fun_1 <- function(df, var_1) {
  
  quants <- quantile(df[[var_1]], c(.25, .75))
  
  tmp_1 <- df %>%
    # selecting var_1
    select({{var_1}}) %>%
    # creating a new variable classifying Q1 and Q4
    mutate(
      expression =
        case_when(
          {{var_1}} >= quants[["75%"]] ~ sprintf(
            "High expression ( >= %.02f )", quants[["75%"]]),
          {{var_1}} <= quants[["25%"]] ~ sprintf(
            "Low expression ( <= %.02f )", quants[["25%"]]),
          .default = NA)) %>%
    # excluding Q2 and Q3
    filter(!is.na(expression))
          
  tmp_1
}

fun_1(iris, "Sepal.Length")
```

After running the code, I get the following output: output of the function:

[image: output of the function with Iris dataset]

However, I expect the function to remove values between the first (Q1) and third quartile (Q3), including low expression values (below Q1) and high expression values (above Q4).

Comment: are you able to share a reproducible data example?

Comment: Sure! I added a test dataset to the question! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `{{var_1}}` is not working as intended there. A way to fix that is to convert `var_1` to a symbol and use rlang's `!!` referencing.

```r
fun_2 <- function(df, var_1) {
  library(dplyr)
  sym <- as.symbol(var_1)
  quants <- quantile(df[[var_1]], c(0.25, 0.75), names = FALSE)
  df %>% 
    select(!!sym) %>%
    mutate(expression = case_when(
      !!sym < quants[1] ~ sprintf("Low expression ( < %.02f )", quants[1]),
      !!sym >= quants[2] ~ sprintf("High expression ( >= %.02f )", quants[2]),
      .default = "NA")
    ) %>%
    filter(expression != "NA")
}
fun_2(iris, "Sepal.Length")
#    Sepal.Length                  expression
# 1           4.9   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 2           4.7   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 3           4.6   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 4           5.0   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 5           4.6   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 6           5.0   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 7           4.4   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 8           4.9   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 9           4.8   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 10          4.8   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 11          4.3   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 12          4.6   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 13          4.8   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 14          5.0   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 15          5.0   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 16          4.7   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 17          4.8   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 18          4.9   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 19          5.0   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 20          4.9   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 21          4.4   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 22          5.0   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 23          4.5   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 24          4.4   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 25          5.0   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 26          4.8   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 27          4.6   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 28          5.0   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 29          7.0 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 30          6.4 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 31          6.9 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 32          6.5 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 33          4.9   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 34          6.6 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 35          5.0   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 36          6.7 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 37          6.4 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 38          6.6 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 39          6.8 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 40          6.7 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 41          6.7 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 42          5.0   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 43          7.1 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 44          6.5 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 45          7.6 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 46          4.9   Low expression ( < 5.10 )
# 47          7.3 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 48          6.7 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 49          7.2 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 50          6.5 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 51          6.4 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 52          6.8 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 53          6.4 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 54          6.5 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 55          7.7 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 56          7.7 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 57          6.9 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 58          7.7 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 59          6.7 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 60          7.2 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 61          6.4 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 62          7.2 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 63          7.4 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 64          7.9 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 65          6.4 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 66          7.7 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 67          6.4 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 68          6.9 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 69          6.7 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 70          6.9 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 71          6.8 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 72          6.7 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 73          6.7 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
# 74          6.5 High expression ( >= 6.40 )
```

If you read some of dplyr's "programming" docs out there, some try to make this even more convenient (to users) by removing the need for quotes around the symbol name. While I suggest that adding this non-standard evaluation (NSE) looks neat, it can sometimes make troubleshooting more difficult, especially for newer R users/programmers. But if you really want it, you could so something like this for the same results:

```r
fun_3 <- function(df, var_1) {
  library(dplyr)
  sym <- rlang::enquo(var_1)
  quants <- quantile(pull(df, !!sym), c(0.25, 0.75), names = FALSE)
  df %>% select(!!sym) %>%
    mutate(expression = case_when(
      !!sym < quants[1] ~ sprintf("Low expression ( < %.02f )", quants[1]),
      !!sym >= quants[2] ~ sprintf("High expression ( >= %.02f )", quants[2]),
      .default = "NA")
    ) %>%
    filter(expression != "NA")
}
fun_3(iris, Sepal.Length) # notice no quotes needed
```

Comment: The problem is that the function's output is always a high expression, regardless of the values in var_1. In other words, it ignores not only Q2 and Q3, but also Q1.

Comment: Your example shows that you are only concerned with the quantiles of the one column.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're intending to happen, but while you select several columns (`1:7 | {{var-1}}`), you are only calculating quantiles on one column and comparing values on that one column. If you need labels for that one column based on quantiles of all of the selected columns, you should clarify that.

Comment: I need to keep my variables 1:7 cause they are clinical features that I will correlate to gene expression (var_1). However, I also want to split my observations into quartiles and only compare values between the first quartile (Q1, representing very low values) and the fourth quartile (Q4, representing very high values).

Comment: The idea is to investigate whether highly discrepant values of var_1 can significantly influence clinical outcomes. One aim of the analysis is to plot a Kaplan-Meier curve, for example, to assess whether the overall survival of patients (one of the variables in columns 1 to 7) differs depending on gene expression levels (var_1).

Comment: I rewrote the question to make the problem clearer. Also used iris dataset as an example. However, the problem remains, all data is being considered high expression and I honestly don't know why...

Comment: See my edit @PatrikdaSilvaVital, I think this should work for you.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much! I was really worried that something was wrong with the way the function was reading the variables (as you can see from the title of the question). However, I had no idea what to do or how to ask the exact question to solve this issue. You nailed it! Thank you so much again!

Comment: I confess that while I understand the intended use of `{{var_1}}` in posts about programming with dplyr, I've not found it to be the most reliable ... more likely, I'm missing some conditioning or something else where I find the same behavior. Glad we were able to work through it, I've learned something too.